# Promisifying Sheet API v4 causes undefined this

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, concurrency, google-sheets

If I use callbacks, the code below using **Google's Sheets API v4** works fine.

However, I am trying to apply `util.promisify` to the API call. This causes:

```
Cannot read property 'getRoot' of undefined
```

which is thrown from :

```
node_modules\googleapis\build\src\apis\sheets\v4.js:592
```

This line 592 says: `context: this.getRoot()`

I am probably not using `promisify` correctly and I hope that someone here can help me.

I suspect it might have something to do with concurrency.

Any tip would be appreciated.

```
let {
  promisify
} = require('util');
let {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
let sheets = google.sheets('v4');
let credentials = require('./credentials.json')

let client = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email, null, credentials.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});

let endpoint = promisify(sheets.spreadsheets.values.get);

async function test() {

  let request = {
    auth: client,
    spreadsheetId: "xxxxxxxx",
    range: "'ExampleSheet'!A:B",
    valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
    majorDimension: "ROWS",
  }

  let result = await endpoint(request)
    .then((res) => {
      return res
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

test();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, after some more digging I got it to work.

I modified my original code to use the following:

```
let endpoint = promisify(api.spreadsheets.get.bind(api));
```

Not sure why api isn't bound to `this`/the context in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the result. 
Edit: If I am remembering correctly async will create promises inside the function. Try the endpoint without promisify inside the async function. 
Edit: Maybe try this, it is possible the credntials were causing some async issue.

I am also fairly certain you don't need the .then() on await .then() is a promise syntax and async/await are slightly different, I mean you can do stuff like that... Let's just see if this works.

```
 async function test() {
      let client = await new google.auth.JWT(
      credentials.client_email, null, credentials.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
    client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });

      let request = {
        auth: client,
        spreadsheetId: "xxxxxxxx",
        range: "'ExampleSheet'!A:B",
        valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
      }
     let endpoint = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get
     let result = await endpoint(request)
     return result  
    }

    test();
```

Comment: I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately, that doesn't help though. The error is thrown when calling `endpoint(request)`. It doesn't even get to the `return`

Comment: Good to know. I am certain that it still needs to be returned but let me think on the code some more.

Comment: Can you try removing promisify from that get and move it into that async function?

Comment: Okay, I've put the return in and changed the function call `test()` to `console.log(test())` in order to potentially see what's being returned.

Comment: Yes, I did try that before. Exact same result.

Comment: Dang. let me know what you get from that log also try logging the client you're getting back...oh you know...

Comment: I edited the code in my answer again...Maybe it has to do with the credentials being async as well.

Comment: Also in that  client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err; 
}

are you needing to return those tokens? I don't know the Google API JWT docs that well.